# Electric field lines of a semi-circle charged ring

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

If I have semi-circle positive charged ring, the electric field lines should come out the outer curved side of the ring radially. What about the inner curved side? According to what I learnt (or in youtube), resultant electric field at the centre of the semi-circle will point outwards (shown in the image below). However, what about the resultant electric field lines that are located in the rest of the space, other than the centre point (in the red space)? Will they point vertically downwards too? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General view of the lines of the electric field of semi-circle positive charged ring
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: This is great! Thanks! May I know what program did you use to create this?

Comment: This is Mathematica 12. 3D code to solve the Laplace equation for a semiring of finite size used the boundary element method (BEM).

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the info again.